# Apache beam PubSubIO write payload size exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to use beam for a replay process to read from a BigQuery table and then write the data to a PubSub topic, but my dataflow job keeps failing with an uncaught exception. From the logs I can see this error:

```
exception:  
"com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 
400 Bad Request
{
"code" : 400,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.",
"reason" : "badRequest"
} ],
"message" : "Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 
bytes.",
"status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

I am using Apache Beam 2.1.0's PubsubIO.writeMessages() with a PCollection of PubsubMessages that I have created with an xml payload and an attribute map containing one attribute. These messages are well under 10MB and have already been sent through Pubsub before they land in the original BQ table.

Example:

```
PCollection<TableRow> input = pipeline.apply(BigQueryIO.read().fromQuery(queryBuilder.toString()).usingStandardSql());
        PCollection<PubsubMessage> replayMessages = input.apply("Create pubsub messages" ,ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, PubsubMessage>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -123;
            @DoFn.ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
                PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = new PubsubMessage(c.element().get("rawXml").toString().getBytes(),
                                    ImmutableMap.<String, String>of("myMessageId", c.element().get("myMessageId").toString()));
                c.output(pubsubMessage);
            }
        }));
        replayMessages.apply("Write messages to topic",PubsubIO.writeMessages().to(topicName));
```

This seems to only work for 95 messages and under. Any time I try to publish more than 95 I get the payload size exceeded limit error. Is this a limit with the Beam PubsubIO?